# Can we list out tables in hive pointing to a particular location in hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql, beeline

Example:
hive>show tables where location is "/user/hive/warehouse/data";

Sample output:

Sample1(table names)
Sample2

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using hadoop fs -ls command.

> `hadoop fs -ls /path/to/data/dbname.db/managed`

You can get the path - /path/to/data using command `show create table tablename`

Example -

```
-bash-4.1$ hadoop fs -ls /PRJ/data/db/DBNAME.db/managed | head -5
Found 784 items
drwxr-xr-x   - admin admin          1 2018-12-11 05:16 /PRJ/data/db/DBNAME.db/managed/upc
drwxr-xr-x   - admin admin          1 2018-06-07 03:07 /PRJ/data/db/DBNAME.db/managed/aisle_pos_text_dim
drwxr-xr-x   - admin admin        252 2019-02-06 16:42 /PRJ/data/db/DBNAME.db/managed/alternate_receiving_wh_dim
drwxr-xr-x   - admin admin        218 2019-02-06 15:44 /PRJ/data/db/DBNAME.db/managed/backhaul_indicator_dim
```

Comment: But I have only hdfs location. I don't have the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Use below command on your data nodes to see all the tables being created there.

```
hdfs dfs -ls <your_hdfs_loaction_path>
```

When you create a database in hive then it creates a directory at the configured location. In this directory you will have subdirectories for all external/managed tables created in hive.

Above command will list all the directories(tables) on HDFS location.
If you have an access to Ambari then you can navigate through Ambari as well.